# How can I change my boot options from within Windows 7?

Tags: installation, boot, dual-boot, windows-7

I installed Ubuntu alongside Windows 7, however when I boot it up, it gives me graphic issues and will not proceed. I can fix it by adding `nosplash nomodeset` to the parameters, but I don't know how to do that since it's alongside Windows 7. The Ubuntu files are in my `c:/` drive, but I don't know which file to edit. Can someone help me?

[image: http://i.imgur.com/lzGMNiC.png]

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would edit the file `/etc/default/grub`, but since you can't run the necessary `sudo update grub` afterwards in windows, I suggest you change that option temporary before starting Ubuntu in GRUB.

In GRUB (hold shift while booting if it doesn't show up) you can edit the start command line and add `nosplash nomodeset`. You have to select the Ubuntu (Kernel..) you want to start (usually the first entry in that menu) and then press "e", that will allow you to add your parameters.

That won't survive a reboot though, that's why if it is successful you should edit the file I mentioned above and run the update command.

Comment: That's the thing, when I boot, it doesn't give me any options. It goes directly to the installation.

Comment: It goes to which installation? Windows? Ubuntu? Are you able to choose between them?